# What creatures do goblins ride in the Elder Scrolls world?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

Do goblins in the Elder Scrolls world ever ride creatures as mounts?

If so what creatures do they ride?

If there are no instances of goblins riding creatures in the lore are there any examples of them either domesticating, taming or working with any other creatures?

Comment: Where are there goblins? Skyrim, Arena? Ain't no goblins in Morrowind...

Comment: @Mazura - Oblivion & Elder Scrolls Online both have heaps of goblins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They domesticate and ride [a variety of creatures](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Goblin):

> Durzogs are reptilian dog-like creatures that goblins raise for war and to hunt down their victims. The goblins of Cyrodiil raise rats in pens for their meat.

....

> The Shadowsilk Tribe are a tribe found in Stonefalls who have managed to tame giant spiders for use as war beasts.